# Database backup on live server gives error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to backup my database for my Codeigniter Application. I used the code from CI's user guide like this :

```
public function db_backup()
    {

        $prefs = array(
                'tables'      => array(),  // Array of tables to backup.
                'ignore'      => array(),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
                'format'      => 'txt',             // gzip, zip, txt
                'filename'    => 'mybackup.sql',    // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
                'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
                'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
                'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
              );

        $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

        // Load the DB utility class


        // Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
        $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup(); 

        // Load the file helper and write the file to your server
        $this->load->helper('file');
        write_file('/uploads/mybackup.zip', $backup); 

        // Load the download helper and send the file to your desktop
        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download('mybackup.zip', $backup);
    }
```

I tried this code on my local server and it works perfectly fine, but when I try the same on live server its show me error like this:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '28e22aafcb89a2b83643700c3f2044de' at line 1
>
> SELECT * FROM 28e22aafcb89a2b83643700c3f2044de
>
> Filename:
>   /home/project/controllers/admin/setting.php
>
> Line Number: 37

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: In order to initialize the Utility class, your database driver must already be running, since the utilities class relies on it.

Comment: @sandeepsure i did not understand! How do i do it ? i have loaded $this->load->dbutil(); this but how can i keep db driver running ?

Comment: Can you able to do it for a single table?

Comment: Noo, i tried to backup a single table but still the same error

Comment: refer this https://gitlab.cs.man.ac.uk/cameron.edwards/uvent/blob/aec4914525655072c4dc51e6013fcc3f67e8ef44/user_guide/database/utilities.html

Answer (score -1):

Where ever this select query is written add ` before and after table-name.

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `28e22aafcb89a2b83643700c3f2044de`
```

Comment: What about dbutil library ?

Comment: i haved loaded it in my base controller @akhil

Comment: check for select-query somewhere inside dbutil